# EE 2.7 to 2.7.1 Upgrade Problem - Undefined variable: template_group

Tags: upgrade, 2.7.0, 2.7.1

I had this error in one page that I have after upgrade.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: template_group
Filename: libraries/Template.php
Line Number: 1959

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: template
Filename: libraries/Template.php
Line Number: 1959
```

Anyone has an idea what the problem is here?

**An Observation that might be useful or not**

Looking at libraries/Template.php, it seems to me that there is a chance that `$template_group` and `$template` will not be set based on the scope and conditionals. Is this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow I got duplicate template groups. I just deleted the duplicates and now it works.

**UPDATE**:

This issue has been accepted by EE as a bug.

https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19746